# How to extract file data from HTML fields and transmit as JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have two file fields I'm extracting from a form:

1. Single file (floorimage)
2. Multiple file select (imageFiles)

After file selection, I want to convert the file data to a  `base64 encoded` string and as `JSON` as shown below, but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is what I have so far.

```js
{
"floorimage" : "/9j/4QtyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAA.....",   // base64 encoded string image value
"imageFiles" : ["/9j/4QtyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAA....."], // base64 encoded string image value
}
```

---

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#multible_btn").click(function() {

        // Single Image Start

        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("floorplan_img").files;
            if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
              var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

              var fileReader = new FileReader();

              fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                floor_image_base = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; 
                var base64 = floor_image_base ;
                 var str = base64;
                 var arr = str.split(",");
                 var floor_image = arr[1] ;
                data.floorimage = floor_image;// g
              }
              fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }

        // Single Image End

        // Multiple Image Start            

        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("upload_properties").files;
        if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
          var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            property_image_base = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
             var base641 = property_image_base ;
             var str1 = base641;
             var arr1 = str1.split(",");
             var property_image = arr1[1] ;
             data.imageFiles=property_image; // g
          }
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }

        // Multiple Image End

        var data = {
            "floorimage" :"",
            "imageFiles" :"",
        }

        console.log(data);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Single images: <input type="file" name="img" id="floorplan_img"> <br><br>
  Multiple images: <input type="file" name="img" id="upload_properties" multiple>

  <input type="button" id="multible_btn" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: When asking for help, take the time and trouble to format your code readably -- consistent indentation, etc.

Comment: I am not able to pass the json array format in my values

Comment: Um...okay? That has nothing whatsoever to do with my comment above.

Comment: @SagunthalaK, careful, people see these comments. You may really need help now and sometime in the future, and if you disregard good advice from good members you're just hurting yourself.  The guy you're talking to is one of the best experts if not *the* best JavaScript expert on the forum. Pretending you didn't understand him or don't care about what he's asking of you isn't too bright in my opinion. Yeah, I'm the guy who did you a favor and cleaned up your sloppy unclear post.